# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser find elements with multiple attributes

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser but can't figure out how to get the following :

Imagine I have this :

```
<td style"color:#e05206" width"22" height="58">OK</td>
<td style"color:#e05206" width"22" height="58" align="center">NOT OK</td>
<td style"color:#ffffff" width"22" height="58">NOT OK</td>
```

I want to get OK.

I tried something like this :

```
$results = $html->find('td[style*=color:#e05206], td[width*="22"], td[height*=58], td[!align]');
```

I thought that it would be the right answer, but it is not, because it applies an `OR` and not an `AND`.

I want to get only OK and not all the elements.
To summarize i would like the td that has V AND X AND Y AND NOT Z.
Is it possible ?

Thanks for your answers !

**Update :** 
I am not searching to get OK, it could be anything else.
I am searching to get a td that has an attribute V=something AND X=something AND Y=something AND NOT Z.

Comment: I guess your making things complicated, using jquery this can achieved easily. `$('td').each(function(){ if(($('this').text())=='OK') { //do something}      });`

Comment: What about using `find('td[style="color:#e05206"]');` then foreach results to check `if ($e->hasAttribute(align) == false){ // do something }`

Comment: Im not sure. But try $html->find('td[style*=color:#e05206][!align]). In jQuery you can combine attributes-selectors.Simple HTML Parser works jQuery-Like.

Comment: @Turcia It could be a solution. But my parsing is complex and i would like a more generic solution.

Comment: @dreamweiver - I think the point is to get at it without knowing the text.

Comment: ok, not a problem, now if the text is dynamic, then compare the variable with the text value based on whatever is stored in it. anyway logic remains same,even with any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is what i have done.

I used the ganon lib.

```
$results = $html('td[style + width + height + !align]');
```

The lib takes care of pretty much everything.

https://code.google.com/p/ganon/

Comment: This is certainly far from standard css, so I wonder if it's a good idea to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var OkElement = new Array();
$("table tr").find("td").each(function(){
   tdValue = $(this).text();
   if(tdValue == "OK"){
      OkElement.push($(this).attr('id');
   }
});
```

Explanation : Here We are looping all the td DOM Elements and then checking for OK Value.
For Each loop this indicates current td elements and getting the td value and checking whether text value is OK or not if it is OK value then we pushing the td elemtnt ID into array.
Finally array contains only td element Ids which contains OK text. 
Note : You should give unique id for each td element.

```
    <td id="x1" style"color:#e05206" width"22" height="58">OK</td>
    <td id="x2" style"color:#e05206" width"22" height="58" align="center">NOT OK</td>
    <td id="x3" style"color:#ffffff" width"22" height="58">NOT OK</td>
```

Because eventhough you are getting td element you cant manipulate on the corresponding td element without having id.
Now you will get x1 in OkElement Array now you can manipulate that div as you wish Example

```
for(var i=0;i<OkElement.length;i++){
    $("#"+OkElement[i]).attr('style','background-color : red');
}
```

Here in my example i am applying background color red for td elements whose have OK

Comment: I am getting the HTML from an extern source. I can only parse it.

Comment: can u re arrange the sentence

Comment: oh i got it you are saying you cant add ids in table is it?

Comment: so we can get that in another way also

Answer (score 0):

```
var OkElement = new Array();
$("table tr").find("td").each(function(){
   tdValue = $(this).text();
   if(tdValue == "OK"){
      OkElement.push($(this).css('color')
   }
});

Explanation : Here We are looping all the td DOM Elements and then checking for OK Value.
    for Each loop this indicates current td elements and getting the td value and checking whether text value is OK or not if it is OK value then we pushing the td elemtnt color style into array...
    Finally array contains only #e05206 which contains OK text. 





    Now you will get #e05206 in OkElement Array now you can manipulate that tds as you wish
    Example
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to be able to get at that one with:

```
'td:not([align])[style="color:#e05206"]'
```

or

```
'td[style="color:#e05206"]:not([align])'
```

You can't do that with simple html dom though because *it is simple.*

The good news is you can do it with phpquery.

Comment: it seems that phpquery is not updated anymore... I used ganon instead.

Comment: Not a bad choice but I still consider phpquery to be the best for now.